# How to manage Environment and Region/location Specific Configuration using Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

We have following 3 [DEV,STAGING,PROD] environment. And multiple regions/location under each environment example  [ ASIA,EUROPE,US ]. What is best way we can configure the project using maven so that it can pick correct configuration xml and properties  based on the environment and region.

For example: if we want to test/build our application in STAGING on US region, STAGING-US.xml , STAGING-US.properties should be taken during the build.

Our application is Maven based .
It would be great help if you could suggest any other better alternative also, we are trying to use maven profile. But it seems we have to create multiple profiles.

Comment: Never build an application env/stage dependent. Better load the properties from outside of the app...

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise. Our initial Idea is to externalize the configuration could you suggest some way.

Comment: Where do you deploy? On tomcat/application servers?

Comment: So basically its an e2e test application, which is maven based and it uses  cucumber,junit and rest assured, so we are only using maven for executing test

Comment: Using maven to run e2e or do you use JUnit Jupiter ??? And what kind of test application? spring Boot App or classical EE app  or simple war app in tomcat or alike???